# DBUnit cannot import data into HSQLDB

Tags: hsqldb, dbunit, unitils

I use Hibernate in **create-drop** mode to create tables at startup.
(tables are created in the **public** schema in hsqlDB).

For some reason, DBunit is not able to add data into my table:

```
ERROR org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet - 
Table 'MY_TABLE' not found in tableMap=org.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap[_tableNames=[], _tableMap={}, _caseSensitiveTableNames=false]
```

...

```
Caused by: org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: MY_TABLE
```

I am using unitils annotation @DataSet.

I suspect that DBunit is not using the correct schema, but cannot find a solution to this issue.

*Note : hibernate works OK, I see successful requests at startup*.

Has anyone faced the same problem ? Am I missing something ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution is in unitils.properties :

> database.schemaNames=PUBLIC